# OWIN package after upgrade gives an internal error(500)

Tags: c#, authentication, token, owin

I upgraded OWIN libraries from version 3.0.1 to 4.2.0, but after upgrading when I hit from postman api\token endpoint it gives me 500 internal error, there are no error reasons seen anywhere, I changed in app.config to use the new version, any help what I'm missing after upgrade to the latest version, or any way to find errors?

```
   var uri = new Uri(address);
    if (WcfHelper.IsLocalHost(uri.Host))
    {
        var options = new StartOptions();
        options.Urls.Add(uri.ToString());
        options.Urls.Add($"{uri.Scheme}://localhost:{uri.Port}{uri.AbsolutePath}");            
        
        _owinWeb = WebApp.Start<Startup>(options);
    }
```

Comment: Eagerly waiting for help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today and I've managed to fix it in my solution.  I found another project which also used Owin and I hadn't updated it to 4.2.0 so I can suggest doing a solution-side Nuget package consolidation check.

Comment: I have updated everywhere, how to see the errors, any way to trace down whats impacting

Comment: Like your opening comment, I too could not see any actual errors.